# PHP/PSQL/SQL Does a resource always return on successful query?

Tags: php, sql, resources, psql

I am writing some business critical queries and am relying on is_resource to filter all failed queries (ie, bad syntax etc.)

Take this query for example:

```
$result = pg_query('SELECT * FROM logs');

if (!is_resource($result)) {
    die('Error');
}
```

Will that also `die('Error')` if the query works but no rows are returned? I need it to return a resource even if no rows have been returned from the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quote from php.net:
"If an error occurs, and FALSE is returned, details of the error can be retrieved using the pg_last_error() function if the connection is valid."
"A query result resource on success or FALSE on failure."

That sounds like there will always be a resource as result as long as there was no error.

Answer (score 1):

There will be a resource if there is no error. To check rows, you want to use [pg_num_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-num-rows.php).